# Is there a way to create an 'indicator' in an SQL(DB2) select query to indicate when a column is filled?

Tags: sql, db2

This title is vague as hell and doesn't completely cover the problem, but I don't know how else to word it. Basically, I have the following situation:

I have two tables:

Table 1: COMPANY. shows company parent-child structure

| company | parent-company |
| --- | --- |
| A | NULL |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | A |
| E | B |

Table 2: ACCOUNTS. accounts linked to companies

| company | account-id | account-currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 1234 | EUR |
| B | 5678 | GBP |
| C | 7777 | EUR |

What I want is to retrieve the child companies of an input company, which for argument's sake is company A. And of those child companies I want to know if there are any accounts linked to them. I do not want to know which ones, just if there are accounts linked to them.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM COMPANY A
left join ACCOUNTS B
ON A.company = B.company
WHERE A.parent-company = 'A'
```

This gives me the child companies linked to parent company A + every account linked to those child companies. This means that for company B I get two rows with two accounts.

| company | parent-company | account-id | account-currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | 1234 | EUR |
| B | A | 5678 | GBP |
| C | A | 7777 | EUR |
| D | A | NULL | NULL |

If I add a case statement to that query, to just signify if there is an account, the query looks like this:

```
SELECT A.company
      ,A.parent-company
      ,CASE WHEN (B.account-id IS NULL) AND (B.account-currency IS NULL)
       THEN 'N'
       ELSE 'Y'
       END AS account-present 
FROM COMPANY A
left join ACCOUNTS B
ON A.company = B.company
WHERE A.parent-company = 'A'
```

This results in the following table:

| company | parent-company | account-present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | Y |
| B | A | Y |
| C | A | Y |
| D | A | N |

Seems like I'm getting somewhere but what I really want is this:
one row per company with an indicator whether there are accounts.

| company | parent-company | account-present |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | A | Y |
| C | A | Y |
| D | A | N |

Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried multiple things but I can't get my
code to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want `exists`?

```
select c.company, c.parent_company,
       (case when exists (select 1 from accounts a where a.company = c.company)
             then 'Y' else 'N'
        end) as has_account
from company c
where c.parent_company = 'A';
```

Comment: thank you! This works when I adjust the where clause to: Where c.parent_company = 'A'

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe the cleanest way using recent Db2 levels

```
SELECT 
    A.*
,   B.COMPANY IS NOT NULL AS ACCOUNT_PRESENT
FROM COMPANY A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY FROM ACCOUNTS) B
USING ( COMPANY )
WHERE A.PARENT_COMPANY = 'A'
```

If you want the `ACCOUNT_PRESENT` to be a character not a BOOLEAN column, and don't want to use JOIN USING, you could do this

```
SELECT 
    A.*
,   CASE WHEN B.COMPANY IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS ACCOUNT_PRESENT
FROM COMPANY A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COMPANY FROM ACCOUNTS) B
ON  A.COMPANY = B.COMPANY
WHERE A.PARENT_COMPANY = 'A'
```

Comment: I couldn't get the first one to work (And I only just realized that naming a table company and having a field called company isn't handy for questions like this) but the second one works like a charm!